# Django Rest Framework remove csrf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-csrf

I know that there are answers regarding Django Rest Framework, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have an application which has authentication and some functionality.
I added a new app to it, which uses Django Rest Framework. I want to use the library only in this app. Also I want to make POST request, and I always receive this response:

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

I have the following code:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url


urlpatterns = patterns(
    'api.views',
    url(r'^object/$', views.Object.as_view()),
)

# views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


class Object(APIView):

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

I want add the API without affecting the current application.
So my questions is how can I disable CSRF only for this app ?

Comment: You are already using @csrf_exempt token. You can use this on the whole view. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: No, I still got the detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." message. I concluded from the answers that I should remove the default authentication.

Comment: I was running into a VERY similar situation using Token authentication. For anyone else in the same boat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789301/django-rest-framework-w-tokenauthentication-issue-with-csrf-cors

Answer (score 290, accepted):

**Note: Disabling CSRF is unsafe from security point of view. Please use your judgement to use the below method.**

**Why this error is happening?**

This is happening because of the default `SessionAuthentication` scheme used by DRF. DRF's `SessionAuthentication` uses Django's session framework for authentication which requires CSRF to be checked.

When you don't define any `authentication_classes` in your view/viewset, DRF uses this authentication classes as the default.

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'= (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
),
```

Since DRF needs to support both session and non-session based authentication to the same views, it enforces CSRF check for only authenticated users. This means that only authenticated requests require CSRF tokens and anonymous requests may be sent without CSRF tokens.

If you're using an AJAX style API with SessionAuthentication, you'll need to include a valid CSRF token for any "unsafe" HTTP method calls, such as `PUT, PATCH, POST or DELETE` requests.

**What to do then?**

Now to disable csrf check, you can create a custom authentication class `CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication` which extends from the default `SessionAuthentication` class. In this authentication class, we will override the `enforce_csrf()` check which was happening inside the actual `SessionAuthentication`.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication 

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening
```

In your view, then you can define the `authentication_classes` to be:

```
authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
```

This should handle the csrf error.

Comment: Sorry maybe I missed the point, but isn't a security risk to bypass/disable the csrf protection?

Comment: @Paolo OP needed to disable the CSRF authentication for a particular API. But yes, its a security risk to disable the csrf protection. If one needs to disable session authentication for a particular use case, then he can use this solution.

Comment: Hey @RahulGupta - Is there no way to check for csrf_exempt decorator on the view, and then only disable the enforce_csrf for those views?

Comment: @Abhishek Maybe you are looking for the the below [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34316546/4921103) by bixente57. It disables csrf for custom views.

Comment: @RahulGupta if you dont want to enforce_csrf , then what will be best way ?

Comment: To disable csrf globally in DRF. Replace the `SessionAuthentication` with the above `CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication` in DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES setting. Solve my problem. However not sure how big a risk it is.

Comment: You can also make a decorator using this class to reuse it easier:
`def ignore_csrf(view_func):
    return authentication_classes([CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication])(view_func)`

And use `@ignore_csrf` instead of the `@csrf_exempt`

Comment: Where is `SessionAuthentication` located? Where should we put the new class?

Comment: You should add a bold disclaimer at the top of your answer that this is unsafe.

Comment: @MarkE.Haase You are right. Updated the ans to include the security disclaimer at the top too apart from the comments.

Answer (score 44):

Easier solution:

In views.py, use django-braces' `CsrfExemptMixin` and `authentication_classes`:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin


class Object(CsrfExemptMixin, APIView):
    authentication_classes = []

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

Comment: FYI, the authentication_classes line seems to be the key.  Works the same for me with or without the CsrfExemptMixin.

Comment: authentication_classes = [], means there are no authentications to access entity (class/function/url), which seems perfect way to by pass any authentication.

Answer (score 21):

Modify urls.py

If you manage your routes in urls.py, you can wrap your desired routes with csrf_exempt() to exclude them from the CSRF verification middleware.

```
import views

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^object/$', csrf_exempt(views.ObjectView.as_view())),
    ...
)
```

Alternatively, as a Decorator
Some may find the use of the @csrf_exempt decorator more suitable for their needs

for instance,

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

should get the Job Done!

Comment: this worked for me with python3 and django 1.11 and seems easiest!

Comment: The decorator does not work for me. Is there any other condition for it to work?

Comment: This does not work with Django REST Framework.

Comment: The DRF's APIView and ViewSetMixin already use the `csrf_exempt` decorator.

Doesn't work because the `enforce_csrf`'s call to `check.process_view` doesn't pass the decorated view in (there is None as the second argument).

Answer (score 18):

For all who did not find a helpful answer. Yes DRF automatically removes CSRF protection if you do not use `SessionAuthentication` AUTHENTICATION CLASS, for example, many developers use only JWT:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
```

But issue `CSRF not set` may be occurred from some another reason, for exmple you not correctly added path to you view:

```
url(r'^api/signup/', CreateUserView),  # <= error! DRF cant remove CSRF because it is not as_view that does it!
```

instead of

```
url(r'^api/signup/', CreateUserView.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 13):

I tried a few of the answers above and felt creating a separate class was a little overboard.

For reference, I ran into this problem when trying to update a function based view method to a class based view method for user registration.

When using class-based-views (CBVs) and Django Rest Framework (DRF), Inherit from the ApiView class and set permission_classes and authentication_classes to an empty tuple. Find an example below.

```
class UserRegistrationView(APIView):

    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to use session based authentication, you can remove `Session Authentication` from REST_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES and that would automatically remove all csrf based issues. But in that case Browseable apis might not work.

Besides this error should not come even with session authentication. You should use custom authentication like TokenAuthentication for your apis and make sure to send `Accept:application/json` and `Content-Type:application/json`(provided you are using json) in your requests along with authentication token.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this to prevent default session authentication: (settings.py)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    )
}
```

Then: (views.py)

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class Abc(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def ...():
```

Answer (score 4):

### You need to be absolutely sure, that you want to switch off CSRF protection.

1. Create file `authentication.py` and place it wherever you want in your project. For example, in folder `session_utils`.
2. Place this code in the file:

```python
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication


class SessionCsrfExemptAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):
    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        pass
```

3. When you want to make `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` requests to your view be sure that you've changed `SessionAuthentication` to `SessionCsrfExemptAuthentication` from the new file. View example:

```python
    @api_view(["POST"])
    @authentication_classes([SessionCsrfExemptAuthentication])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def some_view(request) -> "Response":
        # some logic here
        return Response({})
```

This trick allow you to override method (pass) `enforce_csrf` and the new session authentication class will skip CSRF check.

✌️

Answer (score 2):

I am struck with the same problem. I followed this [reference](http://dammit.nl/p/946&view) and it worked. 
Solution is to create a middleware

Add disable.py file in one of your apps (in my case it is 'myapp')

```
class DisableCSRF(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

And add the middileware to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
myapp.disable.DisableCSRF,
)
```

Comment: This will make your entire website prone to CSRF attacks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Answer (score 2):

My Solution is shown blow. Just decorate my class.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(basic_auth_required(
    target_test=lambda request: not request.user.is_authenticated
), name='dispatch')
class GenPedigreeView(View):
    pass
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an exclusive virtual environment for your application, you can use the following approach without effective any other applications.

What you observed happens because `rest_framework/authentication.py` has this code in the `authenticate` method of `SessionAuthentication` class:

```
self.enforce_csrf(request)
```

You can modify the `Request` class to have a property called `csrf_exempt` and initialize it inside your respective View class to `True` if you do not want CSRF checks. For example:

Next, modify the above code as follows:

```
if not request.csrf_exempt:
    self.enforce_csrf(request)
```

There are some related changes you'd have to do it in the `Request` class

Answer (score 1):

When using REST API POSTs, absence of X-CSRFToken request header may cause that error. 
[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) provide a sample code on getting and setting the CSRF token value from JS.

As pointed in answers above, CSRF check happens when the SessionAuthentication is used. Another approach is to use TokenAuthentication, but keep in mind that it should be placed first in the list of DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES of REST_FRAMEWORK setting.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a problem during a [DNS Rebinding attack](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/dns-rebinding-explained/).

In between DNS changes, this can also be a factor.   Waiting till DNS is fully flushed will resolve this if it was working before DNS problems/changes.

Comment: What has this got to do with the question above?

Comment: Meaning that this problem can occur when you are switching DNS and it has not fully propagated.    If the app has different routing than the Django normal session, this is why.    Just informing of an edge case I ran into.  This seems to be a somewhat canonical resource, so I thought I would add an additional resource.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted after the explanation. I've been saved by people that posted their "Edge cases" on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

For me, using `django 3.1.5` and `django rest framework 3.12` the solution was way easier.

It happened to me that on a `views.py` file I had defined this two methods:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def create_transaction(request):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def create_transaction(initial_data):
    pass
```

On my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('transaction', views.create_transaction, name='transaction'),
]
```

Django was picking the latest and throwing the error. Renaming one of the two solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Code bellow would remove demand for CSRF. Even anon user would be able to send request.

```
from typing import List, Any

class Object(APIView):
    authentication_classes: List = []
    permission_classes: List[Any] = [AllowAny]

    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):

    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ remove csrf protection """
        res = super(VolumeManagerViewSet, self).initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
        return res
```

You can override `initialize_request`  method to remove csrf protection.

Answer (score -1):

Removing CSRF check is not always the only (or best) solution. Actually, it's an important security mechanism for `SessionAuthentication`.

I was having the same issue when trying to authenticate with JWT and doing a POST request.

My initial setup looked like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "django_cognito_jwt.JSONWebTokenAuthentication",
    ),
    ...
}
```

As `SessionAuthentication` was checked first in the list, the CSRF error was raised. My solution was as simple as changing the order to always check JWT auth first. Like this:

```
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "django_cognito_jwt.JSONWebTokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
```

At the end, `SessionAuthentication` for me is only used in the django admin panel and 99% of the requests goes to the API that uses JWT auth.