# Django api : CSRF exempt doesn't work (on Apache)

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-csrf

I am developing this android app which uploads images to my website which is developed on django.

I have used `django-rest-framework` to create this api for uploading files. Now I need to use Forms to save the images(see the code below)

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def create_image(request):
    ImageModel = get_image_model()
    ImageForm = get_image_form(ImageModel)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            image = ImageModel(uploaded_by_user=request.user)
            form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=image)
            if form.is_valid():
                image.file_size = file.size
                form.save()
```

But it gives the error `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` I've tried `@csrf_exempt` but still the same error.

As I re-read the documentation of Django-rest-framework, I found [THIS](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration) which says:

> Note that if deploying to Apache using mod_wsgi, the authorization header is not passed through to a WSGI application by default, as it is assumed that authentication will be handled by Apache, rather than at an application level.
>
> If you are deploying to Apache, and using any non-session based
>   authentication, you will need to explicitly configure mod_wsgi to pass
>   the required headers through to the application.

So, the authentication is being handled by Apache and not at the application level.

Comment: Have you included `{% csrf_token %}` inside the `<form>` element?

Comment: Do you really want to skip it or should it be included?... Also, what does "it didn't help" entail? what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Since i am making requests from android, i do need to skip the verification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework remove csrf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf)