# Django: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: python, django, django-views, csrf, django-urls

I am having a problem with "CSRF cookie not set". All I need is that the external billing platform send the update to the django server. Locally it works with Postman but in the demo server its not working...

## Code

```
# views.py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt
def postback(request):
    print(request.POST)
    return JsonResponse({'ok': 'hoooh!'})

# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from billing import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^postback/$', views.postback),
]
```

## Error

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /billing/postback/
[21/Jul/2016 10:49:21] "POST /billing/postback/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2682
```

## Result of the postback to the requestb server

https://requestb.in/p0rihap0?inspect#t67d6c

## Env

- Python 3.5.1+
- Django 1.10rc1

Comment: Are you sure that request is going to the right place? Show the whole of the main urls.py, including the "billing" mapping.

Comment: Do you have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` in your settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have set the `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to be `True` in your settings file, then the cookie will be marked as "secure" and therefore will need an HTTPS connection.

Which is why you receive that error.

For more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure).

Answer (score 7):

I modify urls.py

If you manage your routes in urls.py, you can wrap your desired routes with csrf_exempt() to exclude them from the CSRF verification middleware.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^object/$', csrf_exempt(views.ObjectView.as_view())),
    ...
)
```

In views.py

```
class ObjectView(CreateView):

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
             #enter you view
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://<my_domain>.com']
```

**the code above work like margic**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
[Django Rest Framework remove csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf)

I use in some parts of the system the DRF and maybe it was generating the CSRF error and ignoring the *csrf_exempt* decorator.

Comment: Exempting csrf has it's own issue related to security. It should not be recommended