# Django - CSRF problem after moving to production server

Tags: django

I moved applications to the production server and I have a problem with CSRF - **Access denied (403)
CSRF verification failed. The request was aborted.**

I checked in my browser and I don't have a cookie named

> csrftoken

Part of my settings.py looks like this:

```
 SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
 
 CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
 
 #SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
 #SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
 #CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
 #SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
 #SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
 #SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
```

I haven't turned on HTTPS yet

Everything worked fine on the development server.
Where to find the cause and what to improve?

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was to add the following to settings.py, replacing "<my_domain>" part of course.

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://<my_domain>.com']
```

**This code above works like magic**

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
You just had to generate an SSL certificate and enable HTTPS.

This post showed me the solution [Django: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529424/django-forbidden-csrf-cookie-not-set)