# @csrf_exempt not working for rest api

Tags: django, rest, django-csrf

I am trying to exempt CSRF validation for a view that handles a REST API POST request, but I am still getting a `CSRF verification failed` error.

I tried the solution given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf) and it did not work.

My code:

**sendmoney REST API view:**

```
@api_view(["POST"])                                                                          
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])                                              
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, ])                                                     
@csrf_exempt                                                                                 
def send_money(request):                                                                     
    if request.method == "POST":                                                             
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)                                                   
        success = send_money_api(request, data)                                              
        if success["status"]:                                                                
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)                                 
        else:                                                                                
            return Response({"error": success["errors"]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**send_money_api method:**

```
def send_money_api(request, data):
    if data["amount"] and data["to"]:
        wallet = Wallet.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        users = User.objects.all()
        users_names = []
        for user in users:
            users_names.append(user)
        if int(data["amount"]) > int(wallet.amount):
            return {"status": False, "errors": "Withdraw amount greater than balance"}
        elif data["to"] == "ravinkohli" and data["to"] == request.user.username and data["to"] not in users_names:
            return {"status": False, "errors": "Invalid recipient"}
        else:
            wallet.subtract_money(data["amount"])
            wallet.save()
            transaction = Transaction(from_name=request.user.username, wallet_id=wallet, date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                                      to=data['to'], amount=data["amount"])
            transaction.save()
            return {"status": True}
    else:
        return {"status": False, "errors": "Missing content"}
```

Error

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.
```

Comment: Why not `@csrf_exempt` on `send_money_api` too?

Comment: I though because it was not a view but thank you it worked

Comment: Quoting the docs: *A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a response.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSRF validation fails for the `send_money_api(...)` view. Simply add the `@csrf_exempt` decorator above the second view too.