# Django/Django Rest Framework - Disable CSRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman, django-csrf

Im looking for a simple way to disable all the `CSRF` validation to can test my API in Postman.

Till now I have tried add `@decorator csrf_exempt` without success.
I also tried create a disable.py file inside the app, but didn't work also.

Also I want desactivate for all requests, so some way to dont have to add the decorator everywhere. This a project that I just got, is already in Production, but I want to start to write Tests first in Postman, later TestCases.

All my views are using a "api_generics.CRUDGeneric",

the declaration of that class is:

```
class CRUDGeneric(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

thanks is advice

Comment: May help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30875830/1507546

Comment: I've try it, but it doesnt solve my problem, I got other errors

Comment: I think you should update your post with these errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@62009030 you should be able to do what @smarber mentioned.. This could also work.. It is a traversed way to add csrf_exempt

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^asimpleurl/$', csrf_exempt(views.CRUDGeneric.as_view())),
    ...
)
```

This could be a work around for your problem..