# Contentful wehook returns 403 when integrated with django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework, webhooks, contentful

I setup a contentful account for downloading videos and its returning 403 when i tried to add a webhhok to an api in my django rest project. I am new to both django rest and contentful.

```
http://my_server_id/testhook
```

I setup the hook and added my api url. So it called my api when the event triggered. But all time in django rest it shows forbidden.What extra measures should i choose when integrating webhook with django rest?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably because of `csrf token`, you should pass it in a header with a `POST` request.
 `X-CSRFToken: value`.
[docs about csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/)

Like @Linovia said in comment, `csrf_exempt` already exempted in a view, but because of session there is still an explicit check.
Here is a nice answer about this problem:
[Django Rest Framework remove csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf)
In a nutshell you could inherit from `SessionAuthentication` class and override `enforce_csrf`.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication 

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening
```

Set it in a view or in a basic Django REST config:

```
authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
```

Comment: It is random string right. How will i know the value of csrf token that should be added in webhook form.

Comment: @SkepticalGeek you can see that string in a response from `GET` request to a server. In case of web hook you probably need to use `csrf_exempt` to prevent csrf check in a view.

Comment: Your answer is correct except csrf_exempt has no effect on Django REST framework because views are already exempted but DRF's session authentication does an explicit check.

Comment: @Linovia thanks for good point, I saw a good answer about `csrf` in a session auth in a DRF, I'll post it here