# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) when csrf is in header

Tags: django, django-csrf

The request header is as below.

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:129
Content-Type:text/plain
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFTOKEN:t5Nx0SW9haZTeOcErcBDtaq6psqBfeyuX4LRQ1WOOXq5g93tQkvcUZDGoWz8wSeD
```

The X-CSRFTOKEN is there but Django still complain about CSRF cookie not set. What happen to Django?

In settings.py, the naming are perfectly correct.

```
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN"
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if [`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure) is set to true.

You would get such an error message if `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` is `true` and you access a site through http instead of https.
Or you need to use (for testing only) [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt).

For example, [curtisp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864097/curtisp) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998530/forbidden-csrf-cookie-not-set-when-csrf-is-in-header/46998552?noredirect=1#comment106319772_46998552):

> I had conditional `dev` vs `prod` settings and accidentally put `dev` settings to `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` and `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`.
>   My `dev` site is `localhost` on laptop, and is does not have SSL.
>   So changing `dev` settings to `False` fixed it for me.

Comment: Tried it. I literally read through all related problem in stackoverflow and google but still no luck tho.

Comment: @MervynLee Strange: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875830/6309

Comment: They are facing the problem with DRF. I am actually sending a POST request to backend(django) for signup purpose, with reactjs. I spotted that by login into admin panel, the header is not x-csrf but is named Cookie:vcubes=JSfUYXtNIMa9NSDZWUMuVpclItFfpsaHGI8HRvznzMmszn5lH68Md9MdSEbOGdpB; sessionid=notinzk6uavo7c3zjpit484fj8dglag9. I am investigating this issue with this direction. I replaced the X-CSRF header name to Cookie but then it wont be appear in the browser F12.

Comment: This helped me. I had conditional dev vs prod settings and accidentally put dev settings to CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True  . My dev site is localhost on laptop and is does not have SSL. So changing dev settings to False fixed it for me.

Comment: @curtisp Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility;