# Disable CSRF on api view method(django rest framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I have such api method:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@login_required
def get_posts(request):
    # ...
```

How can I disable CSRF **only** on this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For function based views you can usually use the decorator [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

***Update***: There may be an exception for the `DRF`. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf/30872613).

Comment: Why did you remove @api_view() from your example?

Comment: Because ``api_view`` is only for DRF. I wanted to explain that the decorator ``csrf_exempt`` is not DRF specific. So I updated the answer and linked it to another SO question, which explains another related caveat (authentication) in more detail.