# Post from Angular 5 front-end to Django Rest Framework back-end

Tags: django-rest-framework, angular5

I am trying to create a post request from Angular 5 to DRF. The field is a form that a user submits. I created the serializer and i can post something from DRF interface

**models.py**

`class UserForm(models.Model):
    id_user_form = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='idUser', unique=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

**serilizers.py**
`class UserFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = UserForm
    fields = ('user', 'name', 'type', 'location')

def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user_form = UserForm.objects.create(user_id=user_data, **validated_data)

    return user_form
```

**views.py**

`class FormSubmit(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserForm.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserFormSerializer`

When i try to post it via Angular I get this error: 
`Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /api/form/`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the exact same problem when I wanted to upload a profile picture to my Django REST backend.

You have 2 options, basically.

The first one is disabling the CSRF checks, which are by default enforced by DRF. Have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf). You may do this for testing purposes.

The second option would be to pass the CSRF Token inside your request header. To do that, have a look at the [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) API.
With that, you can get the token out of the cookie and paste it into your header like so: `'X-CSRFToken': your-csrf-token-here`.

You can verify this by opening your dev tools inside the browser and navigating to your site's cookies. You should see one called `csrftoken` there.

I hope this sent you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I had already implemented jwt. The problem was just an extra '/' in the url (const formUrl = `api/form/`;). The moment i removed it everything works fine. Sorry for the lack of info in the question and i really appreciate spending time to answer me. It helped me figure out other things that haven't completely understood.
Piece