# Django Post 403 forbidden CSRF

Tags: django, csrf

I have a simple Django webhook that keeps returning a `403 forbidden` despite I have marked it with `csrf_exempt`.

Here is the relevant code:

urls.py

```
 ...
 url(r'^mail/$', MailView.as_view(), name="mail"),
 ...
```

view.py

```
class MailView(View):
    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MailTrackingView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

When sending data to this endpoint, Django gives a

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /mail/
```

What else do I have to set so the CSRF validation is not performed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to wrap it inside `method_decorator`
 Try

```
class MailView(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt))        
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MailTrackingView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

You cal also do:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class MailView(View):
```

#### Update

Do you have `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` set to True?

Here's the code I used to test it and it works as expected; if the decorator is commented out, I get a 403 CSRF failure, if it is left then my post succeeds.

#### View File

```
class MyView(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(status=204)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = """
        Authenticated: {}
        <form method="post">
            <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
            <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name">
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </form>
        """.format(request.user.is_authenticated())
        return HttpResponse(form)
```

#### URLs File

```
    url(r'^test/', views.MyView.as_view()),
```

Answer (score -1):

Add { %csrf_token% } in your form in the template.

And declare:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure

Comment: I'm not using any form

Comment: Please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf

Comment: https://dammit.nl/20141111-disabling-csrf-checking-in-django-rest-framework-to-enable-replay.html