# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checks 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: python, django, angular, angular2-services

I have an application that uses angular 6 as front framework & Django on backend. When I use get request everything is ok, but whenever I want to use post I face `403 forbidden` error. Tried to use `headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` on Django but it didn't work any good.
Here's my code:

Check.service.ts:

```
editCheck(check: Check):Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.checksUrl, check,httpOptions)
}
```

check-edit.component.ts:

```
   goBack():void{
this.location.back();
}
editCheck(): void {
this.checksService.editCheck(this.check)
  .subscribe(() =>this.goBack())
}
```

editCheck is called at check-edit.component.html: `<button mat-button (click)="editCheck()" >Save</button>`

**View:**

```
class GetChecksView(APIView): 
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer] 
    def get(self, request): 
        checks = PingCheck.objects.all() 
        checks = PingCheckSerializer(checks, many=True).data 
        return Response(checks)
```

And here is what the error looks like:

> polyfills.js:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checks 403 (Forbidden)
>  
>   main.js:1 ERROR e {headers: t, status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden",
>   url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checks", ok: false, …}

Comment: Is DEBUG enabled on Django?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, it is

Comment: What do you get when you visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checks ? It could be the csrf validation.

Comment: @Selcuk i've got no any authorisation tokens yet.When i visit /api/checks, I get data from postgres db& show it on a page via angular

Comment: @Selcuk so i get json with serialized data of django models

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf/30872613)