# Ajax request to Django only succeeds if there is no sessionid cookie

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have sessions enabled in Django to use Django's authentication framework.

From a html page served by Django, and after authenticating as a user with sufficient permissions, I'm trying to send a `PATCH` request via JQuery's `ajax()` function, and I'm getting HTTP 403 errors with the response detail `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

What I've done so far:

I'm including the correct csrf token in the X-CSRF-TOKEN header field.
I've set `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False`.

The cookie sent in the ajax request includes the sessionid. If I get rid of this sessionid, the request succeeds.To do so, I either delete the session cookies in the browser or edit the PATCH request in the browser's developer tools and resend it with the sessionid deleted from the `Cookie` header field. Obviously I need to re-login as soon as I refresh the page, but in the meantime, I can `PATCH` to my heart's content.

So far I couldn't find out why the presence of the sessionid cookie makes Django deny the request.

Comment: What view are you sending the requests to? If it's a `PATCH` request it's maybe a Django-Rest-Framework powered API?

Comment: According to the django docs the header name is `X-CSRFToken`. Have you changed the `CSRF_HEADER_NAME` setting to reflect the different header name?

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875830/6280433

Comment: After correcting the header name (thanks Fynn!), the token is accepted.

Comment: Thanks Arpit for the pointer to the other question which helped me understand why it worked without the session id. After setting up the REST framework to use DjangoModelPermissions, the API access restrictions are shaping up fine. It's only curl requests that have stopped working now, even when providing user credentials and/or a token, but that's a minor point.

Comment: Apparently, for curl to work you have to add BasicAuthentication (in the REST_FRAMEWORK settings, or, if using specific authentication types for views, in the view).