# Using decorators on Class Based Views causes AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I have a Class Based View called **ChannelAuth** that for testing purposes we have decorated with `@csrf_exempt`. This isn't final, but nonetheless I'd like an answer for the sake of learning.

```
@csrf_exempt
class ChannelAuth(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.data:
            return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Data is malformed.'}, status=400)
....
```

When using a decorator, though, we are "wrapping" the class so to speak in a function.

This means when we use `ChannelAuth.as_view()` we aren't actually accessing the `as_view()` attribute as expected, because it doesn't exist on the "wrapper function" thus throwing an AttributeError.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/auth/channels/', ChannelAuth.as_view(), name="channel_auth")
    ]
```

So my question is how would I still utilize a decorator like `@csrf_exempt` on a Class Based View properly?

Comment: Hold on, this is an `APIView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30871033/67579

Answer (score 0):

The initial solution is to use Django's [`method_decorator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) on the targeted method.

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class ChannelAuth(views.APIView):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='post')
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.data:
            return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Data is malformed.'}, status=400)
....
```