# CSRF_Token in POST method using Vue.js and Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, csrf

I'm trying to send a POST request from a Vue.js template to my API created with Django.
When sending I get a 403 CSRF token missing or incorrect error. Since I separated the front and the back, I don't have a view with {csrf_token} on the Django side.

How do I send my form?

I tried some exemples on the web using cookies but i'm beginners and need more explaination about the POST subject and CSRF

I have a Djano View (and urls associated) juste like this :

```
def get_csrf_token(request):
token = get_token(request)
return JsonResponse({'token': token})
```

Whe i'm requesting the url, obtained the JSON with the token.

And on the Front side i'm using this method to get the Token :

```
getToken: function() {
                this.loading = true;
                this.$http.get('/qualite/get-token/')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.token =response.data;
                        this.loading = false;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        console.log(err);
                    })
            },


addNc: function() {
                    let headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                    };
                    if(this.token !== '') {
                        headers['HTTP_X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = this.token
                    }

                    this.loading = true;
                    this.$http.post('/qualite/api/nc/',this.newNc, {headers: headers})
                        .then((response) => {
                            this.loading = false;
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            this.loading = false;
                            console.log(err)
                        })
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `CSRF` you get by default after user login aside with the `session`, if you're using `SessionAuthentication` (It's the default authentication used in DRF).

You have to send it with each request in the header, you can refer the [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_HEADER_NAME) to know more about the header sent, as it's name is changed and can be configured.

Note also that in the settings you have to make sure that `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` is set to False (which is the default), to be able to read it from the client side JS.

Another path would be removing `CSRF` enforcement per requests (But it's highly **not recommended** for security concerns), you can find more about this in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf).

Comment: Thank's for the answer. unfortunately i'm not using session actually.  Is it necessary ?

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Comment: Hi @ROGGYQUENTIN, did you ever get a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Token-based authentification.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i was encountered with,

the problem was, i had used Class based view and at the time of registered the url i forget to mention as_view() with class Name.

```
ex:- class PostData(APIView)

before :- path('post_data', PostData)

after correction:- path('post_data', PostData.as_view())
```