# How to make post request with CSRF token from flutter to django. Post Request from Flutter App to Django backend gives CSRF error. How to fix this

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I have a flutter app for the frontend and Django for the backend.
I wanna make a post request from the flutter app to the Django server.
I checked the documentation and found CSRF exempt which is not something I want to do
can someone tell me how I can make a post request from a Flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Flutter, only to Django. Also you can try your requests in Postman before using with Flutter

Have you checked out this question [Django Rest Framework remove csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf)?

Comment: Yes, I had checked the answer. As mentioned. I do not want to use CSRF exemption and want to protect my views. so is it possible to fetch the csrf and then add it to the request and make a post request. Updated the tags