# Getting CSRF token missing error on a django rest framework (with TokenAuthentication) public APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I'm having issue with Django Rest Framework and CSRF configurations.
I know there are plenty of similar posts on the subject (like this one [Django Rest Framework remove csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf)) but most of them do not apply (I'm not using SessionAuthentication, nor Django templates), and the way DRF handles CSRF is still unclear to me.

Here is the situation :

- I have a DRF application acting as a backend API with several routes, with Token Authentication (JWT)
- I also have a separate frontend communicating with my API. *Both are on the same domain* (say https://example.com and https://example.com/backend)
- I have a simple `APIView` on DRF side for registration on which I need to send POST requests. This view doesn't require authentication.

When I send the POST request, I get a `403 Forbidden error` with the following message :
`detail "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."`

Here is my view:

```py
class RecaptchaVerifyView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = ReCaptchaSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I've read that DRF disables CSRF except for SessionAuthentication which I do not use. I also read that empty `permission_classes` should solve most of the problems. So I guess I don't need to add `csrf_exempt` decorator (which I tried anyway without success btw).

The route declaration in `urls.py` is the following:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('recaptcha_verify/', RecaptchaVerifyView.as_view(), name='recaptcha_verify'),
    ...
]
```

Finally, some relevant django settings:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what to do with settings related to CSRF like `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`, `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`, `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`, `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`, `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`, even with the CSRF middleware itself. Whether if I need them or not.

From what I read so far, I thought I should not bother about CSRF at all since DRF enforces the default Django behaviour, and I'm using TokenAuthentication instead of SessionAuthentication.

What am I doing wrong here ?

P.S: I also have another public view (login page) which works fine.

Comment: How you test this? cURL, browser, postman? Also, can you share traceback when you get `CSRF Failed`?

Comment: Show your `registration` view and how it its registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line missing in the setup was `authentication_classes = ()` in addition to the empty `permission_classes` list.

So my `APIView` class now looks like this :

```py
class RecaptchaVerifyView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={status.HTTP_200_OK: openapi.Response("")})
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ReCaptchaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And same for the registration view. Spent hours on this one, but this makes sense now with DRF documentation stating that without explicit declaration of `authentication_classes`, default `SessionAuthentication` is enforced thus requires CSRF token.