# Django with djangorestframework-simplejwt results in POST error 403: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): on /api/token/

Tags: python, django, rest, http-status-code-403, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

i want to set up a simple Django Backend with a rest api. If i'am trying to login with the supplied urls, but everytime i try to login i get a 403 error: CSRF Verficatoin failed. CSRF cookie not set.

This are my used apps:

```
Django==4.1.10
# Rest Framework
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-api-key==2.3.0 
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
markdown==3.4.4 
# CORS for rest api
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
```

and my settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS='*, localhost'
ALLOWED_ORIGINS='http://*, https://*'
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE=31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME='csrftoken'
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS=False
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS='http://*, https://*'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES=''
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS='http://localhost:8888, http://127.0.0.1:8888'
```

the server runs on port 8888 with the command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888

The Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

and the Settings for the Rest Framework:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', # only for testing      
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.FormParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser",
    ],
}
```

and these urls are in the introduction of the app:

```
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
```

and now, if i try following request:

```
curl \                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username": "my_username", "password": "my_password"}' \
  http://localhost:8888/api/token/
```

i get the error code 403, as described above.

Do you have any ideas, how can i solve the problem?

Best regards!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf

Answer (score 0):

After hours of testing i found a solution. The url patterns were in the wrong order. I changed it from:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', admin.site.urls),
path('api/token/', csrf_exempt(TokenObtainPairView.as_view()), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify')]
```

to:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api/token/', csrf_exempt(TokenObtainPairView.as_view()), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),   
path('', admin.site.urls)]
```

the admin sites must be the last entry and i removed the csrf exempt for the login url.

Thank you Ahtisham for your reply.